# Java zxing ayuda al leer codigo de barras (java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource.<init>)

Tags: java

Buenas tardes, estoy empezando a programar con zxing, mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Estoy intentando leer un código de barras, este es mi código fuente:

```
   private static String readBarcode(String pathname) throws FormatException, ChecksumException, NotFoundException, IOException {

       InputStream qrInputStream = new FileInputStream(pathname);
       BufferedImage qrBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(qrInputStream);

       LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(qrBufferedImage);
       BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
       Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
       Result stringBarCode = reader.decode(bitmap);

       return stringBarCode.getText();
   }
```

El error que me genera es:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource.(BufferedImageLuminanceSource.java:39)
>       at testWS.TestZXing.readBarcode(TestZXing.java:78)
>       at testWS.TestZXing.main(TestZXing.java:50)

dejo una imagen del código de barra que estoy intentando leer.

[image: Codigo]

Comment: Que tal si pruebas, despues del `ImageIO.read` si devolvió null?

Comment: @leonbloy, que intento despues del image.read??

Answer (score 2):

Buena práctica de programación: Detectar errores de ejecución temprano.

Especificamente: la línea

```
  BufferedImage qrBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(qrInputStream);
```

usa un método que trata de leer y decodificar una imagen, y que puede fallar
(por ejemplo, si el stream no corresponde a una image válida, o decodificable)
Debes ser conciente de esto, y preguntarte: *"¿Qué pasará aquí en caso de error, tirará una exception or devolverá null o qué?"*
Es importarte saber la respuesta porque así podrás reaccionar al error temprano.
Si no lo haces, y (por ejemplo) el método retorna un `null` que no has contemplado, más adelante te toparás con un NPE (null pointer exception), que hay que evitar, porque es poco informativo y confuso de debuggear.

En otras  palabras, la línea

```
 LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(qrBufferedImage);
```

implicitamente supone que `qrBufferedImage` no es un null. Pero no has verificado esto. Por lo tanto tu código es objetable

Ahora, leemos la [doc de `ImageIO.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) y dice claramente:

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting
>   stream, null is returned.

Y muy probablemente ese es el caso aquí. Por eso, conviene agregar un check:

```
   BufferedImage qrBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(qrInputStream);
   if(qrBufferedImage ==null) 
        System.err.println("No se pudo leer o decodificar imagen " + pathname);
```

o, probablemente mejor

```
   BufferedImage qrBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(qrInputStream);
   if(qrBufferedImage ==null) 
        throw new RuntimeException("No se pudo leer o decodificar imagen " + pathname);
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta